# External interrupts still cause VM exit although External-interrupt exiting bit is cleared

Tags: c, virtual-machine, interrupt, virtualization

I'm currently working on a small hypervisor using Intel Vt-x techonology.

I don't want interrupts to cause VMexit, so I cleared the External-interrupt exiting bit in Pin-based VM-Execution Controls. However, interrupts still cause VMexit.

What's the problem here? Except External-interrupt exiting bit, is there anything else can affect VMexit by interrupt?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google terms you should use include `xAPIC`, `x2APIC` and `APICv`. Also, ref https://www.redhat.com/archives/vfio-users/2016-June/msg00055.html

Comment: Thanks for your info. My hypervisor uses xAPIC. Is there any problem with it?